# Implement RS485 or I2C protocol using the usb-c connector?

Tags: i2c, rs485, usb-c

I was wondering if there's any reason why I can't implement RS485 or 12C communication on the data pins of the USB-C connector?

I can't find anything on the internet that tells me not to.

Comment: there is no reason why not ... you can use any connector you like .... make sure that you design in some protection circuitry, because someone will plug a USB device into the connector

Comment: are you aware of the existence of active USB-C cables? having to read USB standards to figure out if it is ok to run something else over their cables doesn't seem worth it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think anything prevents you from doing that, but it is common sense to not to use a connector for something else than it is already meant for.

At some point cables may get mixed and somebody will connect it to another real USB device by accident and it can damage your device or the other device unless you plan for accidental connectivity. Even if nothing gets damaged, somebody could still expect it being a USB device since it has the USB connector.

The impedance of USB cables is nominally 90 ohms, which is somewhat smaller than nominal recommended minimum of 100 ohms and quite a bit smaller that the typical 120 ohms.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I understand your point. usb c is such a great connector that I'm tempted to use it but I have to consider these risks. RS-485 standard connectors are terrible by comparison

Comment: Similar connectors must exist, I do get your point as standard cables can then be used. Perhaps something even more obscure like micro HDMI. But there is no standard RS485 connectors, some connectors are just happen to be used a lot.